# Select data that meet criteria from a table, adding it to a ComboBox in a UserForm

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, excel-tables, listobject

I have a table of data in Excel. Using VBA I want to select values (numbers) from the first column of the table (Active_Accessions) which are in the same row as names in the second column. The names match the name in a ComboBox (cmbxLatinName). Then the results of all this should add the list of selected numbers from column 1 into a different ComboBox (cmbxSourceAcc).

This code seems good, except for `Datarw`, I can't `Dim` it. I know there is a way to go right into the ComboBox but that is too complex so I was going to write the results into the third column of the table where I know how to pull them into the ComboBox.

```vb
'Match source accession to its sub-accession
Public Function GetSourceAcc()

    Dim Tbl As ListObject
    Dim r As Long
    Dim Datarw As
    
    Set Tbl = Sheet5.ListObjects("Active_Accessions")
    r = 1
    For Each Datarw In Tbl.ListRows
    If Datarw.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange = Me.cmbxLatinName.Value Then
        Tbl.ListColumns(3).Offset(r, 0) = Tbl.ListColumns(1).Value
        r = r + 1
    End If
    Next
    
    GetSourceAcc = Sheet5.ListObjects("Active_Accessions").ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange.Value
    
    Let Me.cmbxSourceAcc.List = GetSourceAcc
    Me.cmbxSourceAcc.ListIndex = 0

End Function
```

Comment: `Dim Datarw As ListRow` Then you can access (eg) `Datarw.Range.Cells(2)` etc. to read/set specific cells on that row.

Comment: that didn't work, get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Fill Combo Box With Matches

```vb
Sub GetSourceAcc()
    ' It is assumed that the ranges have at least 2 cells (rows) (each).

    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = Sheet5.ListObjects("Active_Accessions")
    
    ' Source Lookup (sl)
    Dim slrg As Range: Set slrg = tbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange
    Dim srIndexes(): srIndexes = Application.Match(Me.cmbxLatinName.List, slrg, 0)
    ' 'srIndexes' holds the matching row indexes i.e. the numbers of the rows
    ' where each item from the combo box was found in the source lookup range.
    ' If an item was not found, an error value was returned (shouldn't happen).
    
    ' Source Return (sr)
    Dim srData(): srData = tbl.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Value
    
    ' Write the matching values to an array.
    
    ' Destination (d)
    Dim dCount As Long: dCount = UBound(srIndexes)
    Dim dArr(): ReDim dArr(1 To dCount)
    
    Dim d As Long, n As Long
    
    For d = 1 To dCount
        If IsNumeric(srIndexes(d, 1)) Then
            n = n + 1
            dArr(n) = srData(srIndexes(d, 1), 1)
        End If
    Next d
    
    If n < dCount Then ReDim Preserve dArr(1 To n)
    
    'Debug.Print Join(dArr, ", ")
    
    ' Return the matching values in another combo box.
    
    Me.cmbxSourceAcc.List = dArr
    Me.cmbxSourceAcc.ListIndex = 0

    MsgBox "Combo box populated.", vbInformation

End Function
```

Comment: this is an interesting approach. I barely understand what is going on. When I plug it in and run it I get a runtime error 9 subscript out of range error on If IsNumeric(srIndexes(d)) Then  I think that may mean the line of code writing the matching values to an array needs to be added, but I am unsure and don't grasp how to do that in this complex sub.

Comment: Try replacing both occurrences of `srIndexes(d)` with `srIndexes(d, 1)` i.e. insert `, 1`.

Comment: oh snap, that did the trick. It works perfectly. thank you so much. I'll be studying this to understand it again.

Comment: I've corrected the code.

Comment: Actually @VBasic2008 it does not do what I need it to do. As it works now, it loads a full array list to the combobox. But it doesn't check and limit the array by the contents of cmbxLatinName. I probably didn't explain my need well enough. I need it to get the value of that combobox and match it to column 2, returning a values in column 1 same row. One source to match with several answers into the combobox.